# Why would the custom SSIS log provider not show up on the providers dropdown list?

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I am trying to create a custom logging provider for SSIS, but when deploying the dll, it doesn't show up in the list of providers.

The SSIS version is 11.0.2100.60. I tried .NET Framework 2.0 and 3.5. I installed in the GAC, and also copied to both folders below:

```
C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\110\DTS\LogProviders
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\110\DTS\LogProviders
```

After doing this, I opened Visual Studio [Shell], and created a simple SSIS package. When opening the `SSIS\Logging...` menu, the new custom log provider is not there.

The code that I am using now is the sample package provided by Microsoft (*HTMLLogProviderCS*) from Codeplex, and no luck.

Any ideas where I could have missed something?

Comment: Is this the same SSIS version? Did you deploy to GAC or to the DTS folder? If that's the case do you mind saying the folder location? I tried to compile in .Net 4.0, but I can't deploy to the GAC. Thanks!

Comment: sure, if you don't mind, a checklist would help to ensure that I am not missing anything... Thanks!

Comment: Under your project's References, in the properties window for `Microsoft.SQLServer.ManagedDTS` what is the value of the Path?

Comment: billinkc, you've got it! I was referencing the wrong version of the DTS DLL. The problem is that I am working in two different machines. One for VSTS, and another one for SQL. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Here are the steps that I performed to create a custom log provider in .NET 4.0 framework using Visual Studio 2010. The steps also show how the provider was displayed in SQL Server Data Tools 2010.

To begin with, I am using the Microsoft SQL Server Integrations Services Designer version 11.0.2100.60

[image: SSIS Designer version]

Create a class library project. I chose C# and .NET Framework 4, named the project as CS40.CustomLogProvider.

[image: Create class library]

Change the class file name to say `SSISCustomLogProvider`. Right-click on References and navigate to the path `C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\110\SDK\Assemblies` to add  the DLL `Microsoft.SQLServer.ManagedDTS.dll`

Paste the following code into the class:

```
using Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime;

namespace CS40.CustomLogProvider
{
    [DtsLogProvider(
        DisplayName = "Custom log provider created by Siva",
        Description = "A simple log provider.",
        LogProviderType = "Custom")]
    public class SSISCustomLogProvider : LogProviderBase
    {
        // TODO: Override the base class methods.
    }
}
```

[image: Add reference]

Double-click the *Properties* node under the project. Click *Signing* tab on the properties pages to sign the assembly with a strong key. Check Sign the assembly and select  from *Choose a strong name key file*.

[image: Sign the assembly]

Enter a Key file name, say SampleKey. you can enter a password if you would like to.

[image: Strong name key]

Strong name key will be created and added to the project.

[image: Strong key created]

Build the project. I built the project in Release mode. The DLL will be available in `C:\temp\CS40.CustomLogProvider\bin\Release`. Now, it is time to register the DLL to GAC. I found the gacutil in the path `C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v8.0A\bin\NETFX 4.0 Tools`

Open the command prompt in Run as administrator mode. Enter the following commands one by one and press enter.

Change the command prompt path to the location where gacutil can be found.

```
cd C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v8.0A\bin\NETFX 4.0 Tools
```

Enter the following command to add the DLL to GAC.

```
gacutil -i C:\temp\CS40.CustomLogProvider\bin\Release\CS40.CustomLogProvider.dll
```

[image: GAC register]

Copy the DLL `CS40.CustomLogProvider.dll` in location `C:\temp\CS40.CustomLogProvider\bin\Release` and paste it in `C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\110\DTS\LogProviders`. The value `110` in the path refers to SQL Server 2012.

[image: DLL copied]

Create a new SSIS package using SQL Server Data Tools.

[image: SSIS project]

On the newly created SSIS package, click `SSIS --> Logging...` to access the logging option

[image: Logging]

You will notice the newly created SSIS log provider. You can see that it shows the value used on the DisplayName attribute.

Hope that helps.

[image: SSIS log provider]